# Xcode: Set up warning if using iOS 8 and targeting 7.1

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode6

I accidentally shipped a product that's using the new iOS 8 UIAlertController API instead of UIAlertView while targeting 7.1 users.

Is there a way to set up the compiler to warn me about using iOS 8 API on a 7.1 target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly in what ships with Xcode, but there are tools that can help you.

For example there's [Deploymate (which costs $20 USD)](http://www.deploymateapp.com/) but may be well worth the investment.

There's also the [MJGFoundation/MJGAvailability.h open source header file](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Utilities/MJGAvailability.h), which solves the problem of knowing when you’re using APIs that are not available in the deployment target. It solves the problem by tricking the compiler into thinking that such APIs are deprecated. Of course, they’re not, but the compiler thinks they are and warns as necessary.

(b.t.w., I copied that last sentence from the ["Identifying Backwards Compatability Issues" section of this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices)).